# PHP file handling read and write

Tags: php, arrays, fopen, file-handling, fwrite

I am trying to figure out how the file handling works, the thread says:

*Your task is to write a PHP script, which **reads grades from the file "grades.txt"**, raises all of them by one, **writes the raised grades into the file "results.txt"**, and finally **prints the raised grades from the file "results.txt**".
If a grade is 5, it won't be raised. In grades.txt, each grade is on its own line, and the amount of grades may vary. Each grade is 0-5. **The grades have to be written on their own lines to results.txt as well**.*

```
<?php   

function raise($n){
    if ($n == 5 ){
        return 5 ;
    }else{
        return $n + 1 . "\n";
    }
}

$start= 'grades.txt';
$read_start=file($start);
$open_start=fopen($start,'w');


$end = 'results.txt';
$open_end=fopen($end,'w');


foreach($read_start as $key){
    fwrite($open_start,raise($key));
    
}

echo "New grades: ". "\n";
foreach($read_start as $value){ 
    fwrite($open_end, $value);
    echo $value;
}

?>
```

The expected output should be, all the raised grades should be written into the **results.txt**:

```
New grades:   
1
5
2
4
3
5
```

But my code gave me this:

```
1
2
4
3
5
New grades: 
0
5
1
3
2
4
```

Comment: `foreach($read_start as $value){ ` You're reading the wrong file here

Comment: First, you are writting to grades.txt, that's not needed. Second, use raise() function when writting in results.txt (as you did for writting to grades.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) reads a file into an array, so you'd need to take the `key` into account (in `foreach ($grades as $key => $grade) {`). You should also make sure that the values you get are actually integer (`$grade = (int) $grade;`). Then loop over the grades and write/output the new grade accordingly:

```
<?php

$grades = file("grades.txt");
$results = fopen("results.txt", "w");
// print_r($grades);

foreach ($grades as $key => $grade) {
    $grade = (int) $grade;
    if($grade != 5) {
        $raisedGrade = $grade + 1;
        // echo "raising $grade to $raisedGrade\n";
    } else {
        $raisedGrade = $grade;
        // echo "NOT raising $grade\n";
    }
    fwrite($results, $raisedGrade  . "\n");
    echo $raisedGrade . "\n";
}
fclose($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in foreach where you output the grades you still youse $read_start what is the old file without your updates.
This foreach

```
foreach($read_start as $key){
    fwrite($open_start,raise($key));
    
}
```

Should be replaced with inserting new grades to the new file instead of old file.
Like this

```
foreach($read_start as $key){
    fwrite($open_end,raise($key));
    
}
```

And the last foreach should use new file